# Unable to force passphraseless ssh authentication while port forwarding

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I'm completely at a loss as to what is preventing my local machine from authenticating the connection that is being forwarded from the remote server.

I've read a ton of the posts on here regarding this and man, I swear I've tried damn near everything.

The guide I've been following can be found here: http://www.zeespencer.com/articles/building-a-remote-pairing-setup/

Basically where I'm stuck at is in forcing passwordless authentication. If I allow passwords in sshd_config, when I connect to pair@pair-server I am prompted for my local user password and am able to login remotely, so I am being forwarded. But, as soon as I turn it off, I get the following

```
   λ   ssh pair@pair-server 
Permission denied (publickey).
Connection to pair-server closed.
```

Verbose output here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c2b3892596d5ded6abb

I currently have my local user key.pub in pair@pair-server's .ssh/authorized_keys which are command directed to ssh back to localhost. pair@pair-server has it's own key, on my computer I've added pair@pair-server's key.pub to .ssh/authorized_keys.

Seemingly relevant lines in sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
UseLogin no
```

`account` and `session` settings in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` on pair-server:

```
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

`password-auth` configuration:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Comment: What does the server have in its PAM configuration for `account` and `session`?

Comment: @AndrewB updated my question to include the server's PAM configuration for account and session.

Comment: What about the contents of the `password-auth` file that is being included?

Comment: @AndrewB updated my question to include ```password-auth``` config

Comment: can you do a `ls -la /home/pair/.ssh/authorized_keys` ?